# Spring Boot: move command line arguments to property files

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

We are making mongodb connection with X509.
We have added below propertied in application.properties.

1. spring.data.mongodb.uri
2. spring.data.mongodb.host

But for keystore location and password we do not want to send using command line.
if we send using command line it works
but after removing it fails to start.

We set the property in SprintApplication class using @POstConstruct but that did not solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inject properties such as password using the jvm option or environment value.
Enter at run java

```
java -Dspring.data.mongodb.password=your_password ...
```

or Set MONGODB_PASSWORD to an environment variable.

```
spring.data.mongodb.password=${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
```

You can also encrypt using jasypt.
see https://www.jasypt.org

Comment: We are using X509, and not basic authentication. We do not want to pass command line arguments to send key store location and key pass.